# Send a Table scraped by requests to an Excel Workbook/sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-requests

Beginner here,

I scraped a table using requests from nhl.com, and I'd like to send it to Excel.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/powerplay?isAggregate=false&isGame=false&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22powerPlayPct%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22teamId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=50&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20homeRoad=%22H%22%20and%20seasonId%3C=20212022%20and%20seasonId%3E=20212022'

data = requests.get(url).json()

for i in data['data']:
    print('{:<30} {:.1f}'.format(i['teamFullName'], i['powerPlayPct']*100))
```

I used requests instead of pandas because of the dynamic format on nhl.com for scraping Tables and I don't feel like it creates a dataframe (just like in pandas) to be sent using df.to_excel.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.json_normalize` and pass the record_path parameter as 'data'

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/powerplay?isAggregate=false&isGame=false&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22powerPlayPct%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22teamId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=50&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20homeRoad=%22H%22%20and%20seasonId%3C=20212022%20and%20seasonId%3E=20212022'
data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='data')

# Do whatever math you want here

df.to_excel('nhl_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! I'll try that...

Comment: It works but since I wanna send it straight in a specific sheet, it creates another file with the same name that erases the other sheets. Is there something I'm not doing right here?